# DataTable to Redis Cache

Tags: c#, .net, redis

I have some data coming from an external database in a DataTable. It has six columns and around hundred rows.

I want to export this data to Redis Cache. I looked into the data types of Redis and found almost all datatypes are similar to Dictionary in C# i.e, Key-Value pair.

I am puzzled as to how to transfer DataTable rows to this Key-Value type data structure. A "Value" in Redis List can hold only one column value.

How to export NxN to Key-Value data structure?

**Sample Data:**

```
+==========+============+=======+==============+=====+===+===+=============+
| Error ID | Error Name |   E   |   ror Type   | Sev | i | y | Date Logged |
+==========+============+=======+==============+=====+===+===+=============+
|        1 |        404 | Resou | ce not found | Mod | a | e | 3/14/2018   |
+----------+------------+-------+--------------+-----+---+---+-------------+
|        2 |        500 | Inter | al Error     | Hig |   |   | 3/15/2018   |
+----------+------------+-------+--------------+-----+---+---+-------------+
```

Comment: @mjwills added sample data

Comment: first serialize the rows into a single value and then use it.

Comment: @mjwills Thanks for that meta link

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43252282/34092

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how you want to fetch those data. Here are some cases:

**First case:**

As in the end, all the redis values are byte_string, you can convert/serialize each row into a JSON string and kept it under a key (rows primary key). And fetch each row one by one.

**Second case:**

If you want to fetch all the rows at a time then, use list/hashmap data structure to store the rows under a single key.